# Alternative for svn_buildbot.py that does not require twisted?

Tags: svn, redhat, buildbot

I am running some Continuous Integration servers. Source repository is hosted on **Subversion**, and **buildbot** does the job of compiling and testing after every commit. My trouble is that I had recently to migrate the SVN server to a *RedHat5* system. RedHat5 does not distribute twisted, nor zope (essential components of buildbot). Thus, the post-commit hook script of SVN cannot run `svn_buildbot.py`, the script that triggers the buildbot after each commit.

Does anyone knows about an alternative to the svn_builbot.py script that could trigger the buildbot, but that does not require twisted and zope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using buildbot >0.8.2, you can enable the [change_hook feature](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/0.8.2/Change-Hooks.html#Change-Hooks) in WebStatus and use [post_build_request.py](https://github.com/djmitche/buildbot/blob/master/master/contrib/post_build_request.py) in your SVN post_commit script to trigger the build via an HTTP request.

If you're stuck with an older version of buildbot or cannot enable change_hook for security reasons, then I'd say your options are:

- Using [SVNpoller](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/0.8.2/SVNPoller.html#SVNPoller) to have the buildbot master poll your SVN server for changes
- Have your post-commit hook send emails to your buildbot master host, then use [SVNCommitEmailMailDirSource](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/0.8.2/SVNCommitEmailMaildirSource.html#SVNCommitEmailMaildirSource).
- Compile Twisted [from source](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads#SourceTarball). I've deployed several buildbot installations on RHEL4 and RHEL5 servers this way without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than compiling directly from source, I'd suggest using something like [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).